# How I append the list of Fibonacci series using Generator?

Tags: python-3.x, list, append, generator, fibonacci

I tried to print appending list, but I get "None" in the output. When I debug the python code it displays list with series.

```
`def fib():
    a,b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a,b = b, a+b
    
lst = []
for f in fib():
    if f > 50:
        break
    fibb = lst.append(f)
    print(fibb)`
```

[Here I attached the picture of debug + code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbHec.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It's because `list.append(something)` returns `None` in python. Do the following:

```
def fib():
    a,b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a,b = b, a+b
    
lst = []
for f in fib():
    if f > 50:
        break
    lst.append(f)
    print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Answer (score 0):

`list.append` does not return a new list, it modifies the list in place such as `a[len(a):] = [x]`. Hence, you should print `lst` instead of `fibb`.

```
for f in fib():
if f > 50:
    break
lst.append(f)
print(lst)`
```